# swift: compare 2 arrays of characters, remove one value from each

Tags: arrays, swift, character

Here's what I'm trying to do.  I'm making a game where opponents guess each other's word, and each guess has direct and indirect hits.  See asterisks for where I'm having an issue.

```
var directSum = 0
var indirectSum = 0
var words = ["canon", "cnams"]
var secretWord = Array(words[0].characters)
var guessWord = Array(words[1].characters)
var secretWordInd = [Character]()
var guessWordInd = [Character]()

let dir1 = secretWord[0] == guessWord[0]
let dir2 = secretWord[1] == guessWord[1]
let dir3 = secretWord[2] == guessWord[2]
let dir4 = secretWord[3] == guessWord[3]
let dir5 = secretWord[4] == guessWord[4]


if dir1 && dir2 && dir3 && dir4 && dir5 {
    print ("you won!")
}
    if dir1 {
        directSum += 1
    } else {
        secretWordInd.append(secretWord[0])
        guessWordInd.append(guessWord[0])
}
    if dir2 {
        directSum += 1
    } else {
        secretWordInd.append(secretWord[1])
        guessWordInd.append(guessWord[1])
}
    if dir3 {
        directSum += 1
    } else {
        secretWordInd.append(secretWord[2])
        guessWordInd.append(guessWord[2])
}
    if dir4 {
        directSum += 1
    } else {
        secretWordInd.append(secretWord[3])
        guessWordInd.append(guessWord[3])
}
    if dir5 {
        directSum += 1
    } else {
        secretWordInd.append(secretWord[4])
        guessWordInd.append(guessWord[4])
**}

for var secretLetter in secretWordInd {
    for var guessLetter in guessWordInd{
        if secretLetter == guessLetter {
            secretWordInd.remove(at:secretWordInd.indexOf(secretLetter))
            guessWordInd.remove(at:guessWordInd.indexOf(guessLetter))
            indirectSum += 1
            }
        }
    }**
var score = [directSum, indirectSum]
```

what I need to do is count every time there's a character in Array:SecretWordInd  that matches a character in Array:guessWordInd, remove only those two characters(one from each string), and indirectSum += 1 for every time this occurs.  If there are 2 "a"s in one and 1 in the other, for instance, the function needs to remove 1 a from each. **That means the output of the function for directSum, indirectSum in this case should be [1,2] since there is only one indirect hit from one "n" from the guess word.  *This* is what is making the function complicated for me.**  The number of values in both arrays will not be constant.  I can't figure out how to use a method to do this(.contains is for only strings I think).  Your help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a place to get your homework done for you. :) Post a specific question about a problem you're having implementing what you want to do.

Comment: This is actually part of game logic for a game I'm building.  Sorry if it looks amateurish but I'm stuck

Comment: Haha I definitely know what that's like. Just a tip, try and implement something first and *then* ask for help. Chances are what you think is pretty close to what you need, and it makes it easier to help :)

Comment: Yeah.  I tried running for-in loops but all the property dot syntax I know seem to apply to strings and not characters.  I could have done a better job desribing

Comment: **edited for a better explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into Array, Set and String data types in the documentation, they provide lots of functions to perform that kind of calculations and transformations.

For example:

```
var secretWord = "canon"
var guessWord  = "cnams"

// identify shared letters using sets
let sharedLetters  = Set(secretWord.characters).intersection(Set(guessWord.characters))

// count number of shared letters present in both words
let sharedCounts   = sharedLetters.map{  c      in (c, secretWord.characters, guessWord.characters) }
                                  .map{ (c,s,g) in (c, s.filter{$0==c}, g.filter{$0==c}) } 
                                  .map{ (c,s,g) in (c, min(s.count,g.count)) }

// count same letters at same position and shared
// (if you're making a mastermind game, you should subtract directCount from indirectCount)                                 
let directCount   = zip(secretWord.characters,guessWord.characters).filter{$0==$1}.count
let indirectCount = sharedCounts.map{$0.1}.reduce(0,+)                                 


// remove shared letters (for count) from both strings
sharedCounts.flatMap{ Array(repeating:$0, count:$1) }
            .forEach{ secretWord.remove(at:secretWord.characters.index(of:$0)!) }
sharedCounts.flatMap{ Array(repeating:$0, count:$1) }
            .forEach{ guessWord.remove(at:guessWord.characters.index(of:$0)!) }


sharedLetters  // {"n", "a", "c"}
sharedCounts   // ("n", 1), ("a",1), ("c", 1)]
directCount    // 1
indirectCount  // 3    
secretWord     // "on"
guessWord      // "ms"
```

Comment: Thank you, very much.  I'm not going to just plug this in, I'm gonna take a good look at what this is all doing.  Here's the thing, though: the direct count and indirect count for the given words should be 1,2.  That's why I generated an array from leftover letters after direct hits.  if there are 2 "n"s in the secret word and 1 in the guess, and neither is a direct hit, there is only 1 indirect hit for one of the "n"s.

Comment: That's why I suggested subtracting the direct from the indirect in the comments (rather than combine the two inside the analysis) given that a direct will always be an indirect in the function I used.

Comment: And yes, my intent here was to give you concrete examples of how these foundation functions could be combined because I felt the the vague hints provided so far would not suffice to expose their true potential.  I also believe that your thought process should start with functional programming before resorting to procedural algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said this isn't the place for homework ;)

But here are some pointers as to what might be useful:

indexOf : returns index of element you are looking for, nil if not in set

remove : remove from an array

Comment: I've been teaching myself swift for two months, thank you for extending a helping hand to a n00b

Comment: Hope this helps! I had initially written out a solution and meant to share it but I figured you'd be better off practicing a simple function. Practicing is the best way to learn any programming language!

Comment: I appreciate that; I did spend a lot of time looking for a solution to this that didn't involve a clunky list of conditional statements